# How to hide a parent div in css if there is no a tag in it?

Tags: html, css

I have a html code as shown below in which I want to hide `parent div (class="abc-def")` if there is no a tag inside it.

```
<div class="abc-def">
   <h2>Hello World</h2>
   <a href="https://www.google.com/">
         <div class="qwerty">TYUV</div>
         <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
   </a>
   <a href="https://www.twitter.com/">
         <div class="qwerty">SGHS</div>
         <p>Aliquam tincidunt</p>
   </a>
</div>
```

In my code above if there is no `a tag` inside it, then `display:none` should be applied to `class="abc-def".`

`For example:` In the html code below, there is no a tag inside it. In that case `display: none` should be applied to `class="abc-def"`

```
<div class="abc-def">
   <h2>Hello World</h2>
</div>
```

This is what I have tried but I think more need to be done.

```
.abc-def:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: So if it is `<div class="abc-def"></div>` you want to hide it? Or does it look like something else? You really should give examples of both cases when you ask questions like this.

Comment: @epascarello I have added an example. I want to do it through css only.

Comment: :empty must have no children. Children will also include any whitespace that may be there, including a line break. It would need to be <div class="abc-def"></div> with no whitespace. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: You are requesting a parent selector - selecting a parent element of a given selector. Unfortunately, none exists at this point, but everyone wants it! https://css-tricks.com/a-use-case-for-a-parent-selector/ Javascript will be the way for you.

Comment: What you want to do is impossible with CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the css is not working.  Here's a quick solution with js.  Maybe someone else can explain why the css solution doesn't work

UPDATE: the css now works.  for div:empty to work you can't have any white space inside the div. Check developer in chrome to see that the second div's display is set to "none"

```js
let div = document.getElementsByClassName('abc-def')
if(div[0].innerHTML == '')div[0].style.display='none'
```

```css
div:empty{
   display: none;
   }
   
   div h2:only-child {
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc-def">
   <h2>Hello World</h2>
   <a href="https://www.google.com/">
         <div class="qwerty">TYUV</div>
         <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
   </a>
   <a href="https://www.twitter.com/">
         <div class="qwerty">SGHS</div>
         <p>Aliquam tincidunt</p>
   </a>
</div>

<div class='abc-def'><!--display set to none by css--></div>


<!--this will hide the h2 but not the div-->
<div class="abc-def">
   <h2>Hello World</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added an example. I am wondering if it can be done through css only.

Comment: hi, I've updated the snippet - it now works with just css.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just an added note as shown in the example above in the question.  `h2 tag (<h2>Hello World</h2>)` will always be present doesn't matter whether there is a tag or not.

Comment: but then the div is not empty so the css won't work.  In that case you will need to use js

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` for that by using `document.getElementById("abc-def").innerHTML`.

First give the parent `div` a id.

```
<div id="abc-def" class="abc-def">
   <h2>Hello World</h2>
   <a href="https://www.google.com/">
         <div class="qwerty">TYUV</div>
         <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
   </a>
   <a href="https://www.twitter.com/">
         <div class="qwerty">SGHS</div>
         <p>Aliquam tincidunt</p>
   </a>
</div>
```

Then add some `javascript`.

```
function check() {
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("abc-def");
    if (parentDiv.innerHTML == "") {
        parentDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Now when you call the function check, it will check if the parent `div` is empty, if so it will hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem possible to do it alone with CSS only, use some JS (with jQuery) code lines for this case.

```js
var s = $(".abc-def >a");

if (s.length==0)
    $(".abc-def").css("display","none");
```